# How to get the following planar binary trees diagram in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

[image]

I want to get the above diagram in Latex, but I don't know how to edit it. Any help will be appreciated. I know I had better post my effort here, but I really can not get it by tikz. I find an example written by Stefan Kottwitz. I try to modify his example to get what I want. But I am failed.

```
% A simple Tree
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz
% https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]]
  \node {Formulas}
    child { node {single-line} }
    child { node {multi-line}
      child { node {aligned at}
        child { node {relation sign} }
        child { node {several places} }
        child { node {center} } }
      child { node {first left,\\centered,\\last right} } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just to clarify, are you looking for drawing or merely typing those symbols?

Comment: yeah, I find some rooted tree. I don't know how to change the root (dot) to the |

Comment: Sorry, I'm not followin'. Do you want to type these symbols?

Comment: @CroCo, thank you very much, I post an example

Comment: See latest `tikz` manual. Chapter on `graphdrawing` library. It has an layout (`tree`) suitable for binary tree (page: 408, Section 29).

Comment: Please provide a link when attributing code. Why is this tagged with `xy` stuff and `commutative-diagrams`?